# Question about Trigonometric Integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

So I came across this question and I've been trying to work it out but for some reason I can't manage it. I know that when you have an odd exponent for sine you take one off and make it even, then you switch it to cosine and make $u=cos(x)$

How would you go about this problem when both $sine$ and $cosine$ have odd exponents?

[image]

Any help would be grateful, Thanks!

Comment: If you put $x=\arctan t$ you end with $$\int\frac{t^3}{(1+t^2)^7}$$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this problem you can take the substitution $u=\cos x$ or $v=\sin x$. The second is too long since you have to convert $\cos^8x$ to $\sin x$ and the former is enough fine. Thus
$$-\int\sin^2x\cos^9x\cdot(-\sin x)dx=-\int(1-\cos^2x)\cos^9x\cdot(-\sin x)dx$$

Comment: thank you it makes sense now. I thought that the cos(x)^9 had to be integrated as well.

Comment: Glade to help out, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Write
$$\int \cos^{2n+1} x \sin^{2m+1} dx = \int \cos x (1-\sin^2 x) ^n \sin ^{2m+1} dx$$
and substitute $u=\sin x$ to get
$$\int (1-u^2)^n u^{2m+1} du.$$